# DCF Valuation Models

Tags: valuation, dcf

Does anyone know of any websites that have sample models or mind sharing their DCF models? Trying to get started modeling and can't seem to find many great resources. I know of Damodaran, but his models aren't exactly very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of resources on the internet but I used to use during a banking internship:

https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/templates/excel-modeling/dcf-model-template/