# Free DCF model database

Tags: models, dcf, resource

Over the years, I have accumulated quite a few DCF models (some are my own and some are from others). I am wondering if there is any website where I can upload mine and download those of others so that they are all in one place? (e.g. I assume this would mostly include outdated models from banks or student models - anything not bound by NDAs...)

Not sure if this is the right SE for this but seems like it is as I found a [related but unanswered question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47201/dcf-valuation-models).

Comment: Not aware of any but why not GitHub or similar?

Comment: Thanks @Bob, the idea did cross my mind but Github is really built to upload code (usually not large in size) and is not particularly well suited towards hosting loads of spreadsheets all in one repo.

Comment: Be careful uploading other people’s models, as they will be subject to copyright.